# python: How can I check if user input is in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

I am building a S&P500 app using streamlit, the functionality of the app prompts user to either choose number of plots to be shown from the slider or to type a specific symbol to show its plot, however, I am facing problems in trying to check if the symbol exists in the **pandas series** which contains all the symbols,(note both the user input and the symbol in the series is of type string) can anybody please tell me how can I fix it

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import base64
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import yfinance as yf

@st.cache
def load_data():
    url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies"
    html = pd.read_html(url, header=0)
    df = html[0]
    return df

df = load_data()
df = df[0]

sector_unique = sorted( df['GICS Sector'].unique() )
selected_sector = st.sidebar.multiselect('Sector', sector_unique, sector_unique)

df_selected_sector = df[(df['GICS Sector'].isin(selected_sector))]
data = yf.download(
        tickers = list(df_selected_sector[:10].Symbol),
        period = "ytd",
        interval = "1d",
        group_by = 'ticker',
        auto_adjust = True,
        prepost = True,
        threads = True,
        proxy = None
    )

num_company = st.sidebar.slider('Number of companies for plots', 1, 10)

spec_symbol = st.sidebar.text_input("OR choose a specific symbol ")

if spec_symbol:
    if(spec_symbol == (a for a in df['Symbol'].items())):
        spec_data = yf.download(
                tickers = spec_symbol,
                period = "ytd",
                interval = "1d",
                group_by = 'ticker',
                auto_adjust = True,
                prepost = True,
                threads = True,
                proxy = None
            )
    else:
        st.sidebar.write("Symbol not found")
```

despite the user input symbol being valid or not, it keeps giving me the else statement("symbol not found")
here is a sample of the output of df["Symbol"] to make it clearer:

```
    Symbol
0   MMM
1   AOS
2   ABT
3   ABBV
4   ABMD
5   ACN
6   ATVI
7   ADM
8   ADBE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`pandas.Series.tolist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html) (*that returns a list*) instead of [`pandas.Series.items`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.items.html) (*that returns an iterable*).

Replace this :

```
if(spec_symbol == (a for a in df['Symbol'].items())):
```

By this :

```
if(spec_symbol == (a for a in df['Symbol'].tolist())):
```

Or simply :

```
if spec_symbol in df['Symbol'].tolist():
```